# How do I get a payment method transaction ID from a Woocommerce rest api for an order?

Tags: woocommerce, paypal, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, woocommerce-rest-api

I am creating a solution that allows customers to sync their payment transactions made on Woocommerce to a 3rd party software, however I’m currently stuck on how to get the transaction id or reference from a Woocommerce order. For example, if an order was paid for through PayPal, I would like to see the transaction id or reference of PayPal in the order api object of Woocommerce, same applies to Stripe and Mollie.

I tried to use the transaction_id directly on the Woocommerce rest api order object but it doesn’t work, it seems this transaction_id is just a generated one by Woocommerce not the one from PayPal.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can point me in the right direction.

Comment: $order->get_transaction_id(); where $order is object which you can acces like $order = wc_get_order($order_id); And no the transaction number its the same. Unless you use some 3rd party payment plugin for paypal. But stripe , paypal are same transaction ids for me (would be stupid if they werent ). Here is alternative way to access the transaction id -  $transaction_id = $order->get_meta('_transaction_id');

Comment: @Snuffy thank you for your comments. I’m using the rest API https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#orders are you saying the _transaction_id is in the meta?

Comment: That depends on the payment method how they gonna store it. Its just alternative if available. Other payment methods save it in own meta for example _bankname_trans_id. Its not mandatory just giving you alternative if available.